# Difference between rules in based expert systems and conditions in normal algorithmic programming

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence, expert-system, inference-engine

In rule based expert systems the knowledge base contains large number of rules in the form of "if (template) then (action)". The inference engine chooses the rules that match the input facts. That is those rules that their condition section matches the input data are shortlisted and one of them is selected.

Now it is possible to use a normal program with similar conditional statements in some way to possibly reach a result.

- I am trying to find a "sound and clear description" of the difference between the two and why we cannot achieve what expert system rules could do with normal algorithmic programming?
- Is it just that an algorithm needs complete and very well known inputs while expert systems can accept incomplete information with any order?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Rules are more accurately described as the form "when (template) then (action)". The semantic of "when" is quite different than those of "if". For example, the most direct translation of a distinct set of rules to a procedural programming language would look something like this:

```
if <rule-1 conditions>
then <rule-1 actions>

if <rule-2 conditions>
then <rule-2 actions>

   .
   .
   .

if <rule-n conditions>
then <rule-n actions>
```

Since the actions of a rule can effect the conditions of another rule, every time any rule action is applied the rule conditions will all need to be rechecked. This can be quite inefficient.

The benefit provided by rule-based systems is to allow you to express rules as discrete units of logic while efficiently handling the matching process for you. Typically this will involve detecting and sharing common conditions between rules so they don't need to be checked multiple times as well as data-driven approaches where the system predetermines which rules will be effected by changes to specific data so that rule conditions do not need to be rechecked when unrelated data is changed.

This benefit is similar to the one provided by garbage collection in languages such as Java. There's nothing that automatic memory management provides in Java that can't be achieved by writing your own memory management routines in C. But since that's tedious and error prone, there's a clear benefit to using automatic memory management.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing that a "rule-based expert system" can do that a "normal algorithmic program" can't do because a rule-based expert system *is* a normal algorithmic program. It is not only *possible* to write a normal algorithmic program to match the way an expert system inference engine works, that is exactly what the people who wrote the inference engine did.

Perhaps the "difference" that you are seeing is that in one case the rules are "hard-coded" in the programming language, whereas in the other case the rules are treated as data to be processed by the program. The same logic is present in both cases, it's just that in one the "program" is specific to one task while the other shuffles the complexity out of the "program" and into the "data".

Comment: Thank you for your time. I didn't say an inference engine is doing extraordinary things. I was comparing rules in Knowledge base with fixed and hard coded conditions in programs. The rules in KB are not run in algorithmic way (they are run by an algorithm though as you said).

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what Gary said, in hard-coded if-then systems the firing order for the rules is more constrained than in most expert systems.  In an expert system, the rules can fire based on criteria other than some coded order.  For example, some measure of relevance may be used to fire the rule, e.g. firing the rule the success or failure of which will rule in or out the most hypotheses.

Similarly, in many systems, the "knowledge engineer" can state the rules in any order.  Although the potential order of firing may need to be considered, the order in which the rules are declared may not be important.

In some types of systems the rules are only loosely coupled.  That is, a rule's contribution may not be all or nothing.  If a rule fires, it may contribute evidence, if it fails to fire (or is absent), it may not contribute evidence, yet the hypothesis may succeed if some other suite of rules pushes it over a certainty threshold.

This allows experts to contribute rules in a more natural manner.  The expert can think of a few rules and they can be tested.  The expert can add a few more rules, perhaps even months later, etc., all the while improving the system's accuracy without the need to re-write any of the earlier rules or re-arrange any code.

The ways in which the above are accomplished are myriad, but the production rules described by Gary are one of the most common, easily understood, and effective means and are used by many expert systems.